# Parse test name from testng xml to ant build.xml

Tags: ant, testng

There are many testng.xml files which I run via same build.xml using command line option.

I want build.xml to parse the test name from each testng.xml that is passed via command line option

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="tests" verbose="1" threads="10" preserve-order="true">

    <test name="first" preserve-order="true">
            <classes>
                    <class name="com.etc.first">
                            <methods>
                                    <include name="First" />
                            </methods>
                    </class>
       </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="second" preserve-order="true">
            <classes>
                    <class name="com.etc.Second.java">
            <methods>
                    <include name="Req" />
            </methods>
        </class>
            </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

Comment: Why don't you use the xmlfileset option to run testng against all the available test files? Described as an example in the documentation: http://testng.org/doc/ant.html

Comment: What will you do with the test name? Because TestNG listeners are a good way to have access to test names.